# Using Phonegap to build Android application and include HTML5 and Jquery Mobile

Tags: android, cordova

I'm new phonegap developer and want to know that how can I include HTML and JS files inside offline Android application.

I tried [this link](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494774/Getting%20started%20with%20Android%20PhoneGap%20in%20Eclipse) but it's not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation is more up to date (PhoneGap 2.0.0) http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android